# SQL query optimization for speed

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I was working on the problem of optimizing the following query I have already optimized this to the fullest from my side can this be further optimized?

```
select distinct name ad_type 
from dim_ad_type x  where exists  ( select 1 
                                    from sum_adserver_dimensions sum 
                                    left join dim_ad_tag_map on dim_ad_tag_map.id=sum.ad_tag_map_id and dim_ad_tag_map.client_id=sum.client_id 
                                    left join dim_site on dim_site.id = dim_ad_tag_map.site_id 
                                    left join dim_geo on dim_geo.id = sum.geo_id 
                                    left join dim_region on dim_region.id=dim_geo.region_id 
                                    left join dim_device_category on dim_device_category.id=sum.device_category_id 
                                    left join dim_ad_unit on dim_ad_unit.id=dim_ad_tag_map.ad_unit_id 
                                    left join dim_monetization_channel on dim_monetization_channel.id=dim_ad_tag_map.monetization_channel_id 
                                    left join dim_os on dim_os.id = sum.os_id 
                                    left join dim_ad_type on dim_ad_type.id = dim_ad_tag_map.ad_type_id 
                                    left join dim_integration_type on dim_integration_type.id = dim_ad_tag_map.integration_type_id 
                                    where sum.client_id = 50 
                                    and dim_ad_type.id=x.id 
                                    ) 
order by 1
```

Comment: You might be better asking this over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. Please post a schema, sample data, and the output of EXPLAIN.
Without that information, we're just guessing.

Comment: You need a `join` (not a `left join`) between `dim_ad_type`, `dim_ad_tag_map` and `sum_adserver_dimensions`. Every other table doesn't need to be here. You don't need a subquery.

Comment: The subquery is malformed. `and dim_ad_type.id=x.id` silently converts the outer join into an inner join. Are you sure you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query although joined ok, is an overall bloat.  You are using the dim_ad_type table on the outside, just to make sure it exists on the inside as well.  You have all those left-joins that have NO bearing on the final outcome, why are they even there.  I would simplify by reversing the logic.  By tracing your INNER query for the same dim_ad_type table,  I find the following is the direct line.  sum -> dim_ad_tag_map -> dim_ad_type.  Just run that.

```
select distinct
        dat.name Ad_Type
    from
        sum_adserver_dimensions sum
            join dim_ad_tag_map tm
                on sum.ad_tag_map_id = tm.id
                and sum.client_id = tm.client_id
                join dim_ad_type dat
                    on tm.ad_type_id = dat.id 
    where
        sum.client_id = 50 
    order by 
        1
```

Your query was running ALL dim_ad_types, then finding all the sums just to find those that matched.  Run it direct starting with the one client, then direct with JOINs.